# How to configure remote queueing using Active-mq (jBoss EAP 7.2) on both sides

Tags: java, jboss

I did search on jBoss EAP 7.x documentation but didn't find any detailed explanation on how to do the configuration I'm looking for: [jBoss EAP 7.2] <--Remote queues--> [jBoss EAP 7.2 - The actual Queues are here]

As I used to do on jBoss EAP 6.4, I was using Netty with remoting configuration with Acceptor/Connector on Client Side with a defaut remoting on the port 5445.
I'm here to find out the best used practice on how to configure and what are the Actual configurations to be done (which variable on which module etc...)

Thank you community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed the solution:
- Using Acceptor on "Server" server side
- Using Connecor on "Server" client side
Another hint is using the Outbound-socket-binding to choose where to the remote queues will publish/read data.

Thanks community.

Answer (score 0):

You shjould be able to do the same: create a connection factory and a connector on your 'client' server to connect to the acceptor on the 'server' server.

Comment: Actually I did it, but found nowhere to define the IP Address of the "Server" server. Is there a property that I can add the IP Address ? or direcly go through an outbound-socket-binding.

Comment: I'm also thinking on going to import AMQ as a resource adapter on both sides, with crossing fingers on eventual conflicts ... . I will get back here. If working will share the configuration made.